# Pretty checkboxes jQuery selector problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to replace the classic default checkbox with a blocked link inside a div - it would display as a button and by clicking on it it would toggle the class. Actually toggling the class works but I also need a solution how to toggle if the `checked` attribute. See below

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <div class="pretty-checkbox">
        <input checked="checked" id="IsLegalFirm" name="IsLegalFirm" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="IsLegalFirm" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <a href="#" class="checkbox selected">IsLegalFirm </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <div class="pretty-checkbox">
        <input checked="checked" id="IsTaxable" name="IsTaxable" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="IsTaxable" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <a href="#" class="checkbox selected">IsTaxable </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The hidden `input` is there because ASP.NET MVC introduces it when using `Html.Checkbox()` helper.

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkbox").click(
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
                            // this needs a change 
            $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously this only turns on `checked` but when it's already checked it doesn't uncheck it. And I believe it should do it to both inputs.

Can someone help me with a right selector/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checkbox").click(
    function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        var realCheckbox = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox");
        // the problem with this line is that this only toggles the value 
        // of the checked attribute from checked="" to checked="checked"
        // and vice versa and I had problems with this in HTML5, 
        // so I rewrote it as below

        // realCheckbox.attr("checked", realCheckbox.is(":checked") ? "" : "checked");

        if (realCheckbox.is(":checked")) {
            realCheckbox.removeAttr("checked");
        }
        else {
            realCheckbox.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Or you could maybe just force the "click" event for the checkbox, like `realCheckbox.click()`

Answer (score 0):

Not certain the purpose of the links, but traditionally text is bound to a checkbox using a label and the for attribute. Here is an example:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <div class="pretty-checkbox">
        <input checked="checked" id="IsLegalFirm" name="IsLegalFirm" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="IsLegalFirm" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <a href="#"><label for="IsLegalFirm" class="checkbox selected">IsLegalFirm </label></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <div class="pretty-checkbox">
        <input checked="checked" id="IsTaxable" name="IsTaxable" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="IsTaxable" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <a href="#"><label for="IsTaxable" class="checkbox selected">IsTaxable </label></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I left your links in. However, if you don't need them just remove and leave the labels. Here is a jsFiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/bK3ju/1/. Notice no javascript is needed to hook up the labels to the checkboxes.

Bob

Comment: Actually, this is a question about JavaScript. Links are there because I am replacing checkboxes with links (user clicks a link and design changes as opposed to user clicking in the checkbox to toggle checkmark).

Comment: Since you don't have any url on the links and unless there is additional javascript, you don't need the anchor tags to achieve this. Otherwise, you can keep the links in the above code and let the labels bind to the checkboxes to handle the ui update.

Comment: now I see what you've meant, however I like it when the cursor changes to hand, that's why link..

Comment: Also, you have two input elements with the same name. I don't think the hidden ones are necessary. Not certain of their purpose.